# Find value of property according to another property in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem, which I struggle to solve:

I have an array of objects, all of them have same properties but different values. I receive the value of property two and based on it to find the value of property one.

What I tried as approach is the following:

- make copy of the array
- compare if the value match
- take the other value if it matches

But this seems quite ugly as solution.

Any other ideas?

```
const array =  [{
  one: 3,
  two: "some value"
}, {
  one: 7,
  two: "some other value"
}]
```

Comment: What you're asking is unclear

Comment: Can property values be repeated? However, not very clear what you're asking for

Answer (score 1):

Use `arr.find` method:

```
const seekingValue = 'some value'

const objWithNeededVal = array.find(item => item.two === seekingValue);

const neededVal = objWithNeededVal ? objWithNeededVal.one : "";
```

Comment: not sure you wanted to addd the `'` on the second line

Comment: )) You're correct. I've accidently put there a string instead of variable.